# CURL - No output to terminal - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I am trying to get curl output printed to terminal, but consistently it fails and no error message also showing.  For example,

```
$: curl https://google.com
$:
```

Just returns the terminal to the next empty line.

I tried

```
curl -v https://google.com
```

When I checked for curl version with

```
curl -V
```

I get the following response:

```
curl 7.61.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-09-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

I am not sure how to get the output printed on the terminal.

Comment: if `curl -v https://google.com` literally shows *nothing*, then it is seriously broken in your system. See also the mismatch between curl and libcurl version numbers in the `-V` output, which would indicate a **weird situation**.

Comment: @DanielStenberg  I reinstalled libcurl using `apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` and got this resolved.